# What is the proper format for a DKIM type TXT value in a DNS Zone record?

Tags: dkim

I'm setting up Email Authentication and I'm seeing conflicting info on the format.

[Some say](http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=100) that the value should be surrounded in <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>

But other services have told me to leave out the surrounding <kbd>"</kbd>

Does it just vary by ESP (email service provider)?

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formatting of `TXT` record data doesn't really have to do with Email. Ie, it doesn't have to do with the Email Service Provider, rather the DNS server software / DNS Service provider if anything.

`TXT` records [can have multiple string values](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.14).

In the standardized master file format, [if you put quotation marks around something that becomes a single string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-35) even if there are spaces. If you leave out the quotation marks each "word" is a string of its own.
For DKIM `TXT` records, if there are multiple string values [these are simply concatenated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.2).

This means that:
`"foo bar"` means *foo bar*
`foo bar` is the same as `"foo" "bar"` and means *foobar*

For a DKIM record specifically there isn't really significant whitespace, so either is ok in that respect but be careful with `;` as semicolon is the comment character in the master file format.

Now, this is all regarding the standardized master file format, if you instead talk about something like a form field in a web UI of a DNS service provider, then you'll really have to consult their documentation as their UI may or may not accept its input based on the above.

Comment: OK, you answered another question I didn't know I had : ).    So when the Email Service provider gave me a value like "v=xyz;somethingelse"  I need to escape the ; with \;   (or /; I forget) so that DNS itself will ignore the ;   then the ESP will, I assume, parse that whole string, looking for the ; right?

Comment: @ClayNichols If you are writing the record specifically in the master file format (such as a BIND zone file), you need to escape `;` as `\;` unless inside a quoted string. Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/743789/why-do-i-need-to-escape-with-in-a-dns-dkim-record

Answer (score 1):

Yes surround the whole shabang in quotes! Fun fact, dig returns results in bind-ok format, so you can always try digging someone else's dkim record:

```
[d...@o... ~]$ dig @sjc-dns1.ebaydns.com -t TXT dkim1k._domainkey.ebay.com
```

[snip]

```
dkim1k._domainkey.ebay.com. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+mihCTvPRr46AskdAcAP0FLp+PwmRwxUjWXSaQiT0u+iqOaDj8wi9/kRfTJyvkPVAnEa3d9l1hSiVmK7VMTptUldvitfg/T2AVMi5s/B9gJoj30eOujBJHFvCd6Imu4BDCMjZSDWEcbHXH+jsYuNxCG5aeguZwGzaFtsK0iLhDQIDAQAB;"
```

[snip]

Comment: Not adding quotes would make the record "v=DKIM1;" "k=rsa;" "p=ETCETC"